# Add a column in Mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I have created a Db and a collection in Mongodb. All the items in the collection have the following attributes: `name, city, car and year`. I have around 200+ dummy items created in that collection. Now how do I go about adding 1 more attribute, like for example `country` for each item?

Is this possible in Mongodb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `db.getCollection('collectionName').update(findQuery, updateQuery, upsert, multi)` itself to insert a new column.

Example:

```
db.getCollection('test').update({}, {$set: {"country": "country"}},false,true)
```

This will insert a new column country with the default value `country`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using something that maps your application's objects to the database documents? If that's the case, you might have to add the new attribute there.

If you're just talking about plain mongodb, you can just add it to documents that have that attribute. Or iterate over all the documents and add it with some default value. You might actually have to do this as "kind of migration" to if your code requires this attribute on all of your documents.